# Set properties in the way it's declared in c# class

Tags: c#, .net, class, properties

I have a class called "Symbol" and have list of properties.

```
Public class symbol {
  z_prop{get;set;}
  B_prop{get;set;}
   A_prop{get;set;}
}
```

i have done a db call and assign data reader to this class instance. Like the below code

```
//dr is datareader object
symbol symbols = new symbol();                       
symbols.z_prop= dr["z_prop"].ToString();
symbols.B_prop= dr["B_prop"].ToString();
symbols.A_prop= dr["A_prop"].ToString();
```

Gridview OutPut will be like this:

```
   Columns : A_prop  B_prop  Z-Prop
   Values  : Value   Value   Value
```

Everything works fine. But after assigning the reader values, the symbol properties are ordered with alphabetic order. I want the properties ordered like its declared in class. Any suggestion why it's ordered alphabetically?.

Comment: aligned/ordered in what?

Comment: Updated now, its ordered.

Comment: My original comment still stands.

Comment: Show sample data. It is not clear what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you meant the properties are aligned in alphabetical order when you see the symbol class from the debugger window.if that is the case then you can not do anything as it is how the debugger works.

**By Default Debugger will show the all members in alphabetical order.**

Check this below image:

[image]

Comment: That's ok , but after that i assginged the list to grid view, its display the data in the same alaphapet order

Answer (score 1):

When Visual Studio shows you a list of properties/events, it automatically sorts them. 
So you can use your own constructor for your class as follow:

```
Public class symbol {
  z_prop{get;set;}
  B_prop{get;set;}
  A_prop{get;set;}

  Public symbol (z_prop, B_prop, A_prop)
  {
      //your code for assigning properties
  }
}
```

And then you can use following code to assign values:

```
symbol symbols = new symbol(dr["z_prop"].ToString(), dr["B_prop"].ToString(), dr["A_prop"].ToString());
```